# LatexTools not installing in Sublime Text 3

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-3, latex, ubuntu-18.04, texlive

I am using Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 18.04. I have been trying to install the LatexTools package using Package Control. However, each time I try, the package seems not to have installed - it does not appear under "Package Settings" or "Installed Packages", when I try building latex files I get the message "no build system", and Latex is not an option under "Build System". I have already installed TexLive using apt-get install. Does anyone know what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Sublime Text's build system is set to *Automatic*. To determine which build system to use, your current document needs to match the build system's selector. In the case of LaTeX Tools, that [selector](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/cc79e98/LaTeX.sublime-build#L13) is `text.tex.latex`.

Unless there's conflict of some sorts, Sublime Text will assign the selector once you save a LaTeX file with a compatible file-extension. Otherwise, you can set the syntax for any file manually from the command palette (e.g. *Set Syntax: LaTeX*) or by clicking in the right bottom of the Sublime Text window.

If all of the above fails, you can override default build system by changing it from *Automatic* to *LaTeX*:

[image]

Once the build system is set up correctly, it should report missing binaries if there are any.

**Example:**

> Basic Builder: running pdflatex...
>
> COULD NOT COMPILE!
>
> Attempted command:pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 > untitled.tex
>
> Build engine: Basic Builder

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my original question that Latex was also not listed as an option under "Build System". I have edited the question now to reflect that.